# Does New York have a higher number of people with tuberculosis?

Tags: usa, health, new-york-city

I would like to send someone with special needs to [this place](https://www.helenkeller.org/hknc/deaf-blind-immersion-experience), but they require that everyone be tested for tuberculosis. We have never travelled outside of the US, and we've lived in Oregon for all of our lives.

Comment: I'd imagine that this is a particular requirement to live (or [volunteer](https://www.helenkeller.org/hks/become-volunteer)) in the group home where the course is conducted. Institutional living settings are generally considered higher-risk for TB, and the nature of the program inherently involves close physical contact. Regulations often require testing for residents and employees in long-term care facilities, though I'm not sure precisely how this facility is regulated.

Comment: Taco Bell? Teddy Bear? Terabyte? Trackable? Terbium?

Comment: @Neusser Tuberculosis

Answer (score 3):

Yes, apparently, as has one of your neighboring states, California.  See https://www.cdc.gov/tb/publications/factsheets/statistics/tbtrends.htm (emphasis added):

> TB was reported in all 50 states
>
> Nine states, the District of Columbia (DC), and **New York City** reported incidence rates above the national average.
>
> TB case counts were highest in **California,** Texas, **New York (including New York City),** and Florida. These four states accounted for just over half of the total cases in the United States.

Comment: Coincidentally, those just happen to be the four most populous states in the union.  They account for almost exactly a third of the total population of the United States (data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population)).  In other words, they *do* have above average rates of TB, but not by *huge* amounts.

Comment: My comment was specifically related to the last paragraph (which definitely *is* talking about absolute counts).